# Display texts in x-axis distinctly

Tags: python, csv, plot

[image]

I plotted this graph on Google Colab Notebook by reading a CSV file from Google Drive. But as it is seen when I try to plot the stuff , the x-axis data gets overlapped and becomes unclear. My first attempt was to change the scale from linear to logarithmic and the some things got cleared (in this context USA and CHINA could be distinctly understood now) but still Indian countries , United Kingdom , Arab , Brazil cannot be fixed. Is there any way I can fix this ?
Any help is appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into using Highcharts? I've been making graphs and doing exactly what your asking for the last 4 months and it's loaded with features and there example jsfiddles for everything you could image. Good luck

Comment: @JustinMeskan Not actually. Can you please give me some introduction to it  ?

Comment: Its a huge library or multiple libraries, You will have to basically jump in and start with trail and error. I get what your saying but honestly just google what type of chart you want or what chart feature your intertested in and make sure you add the highcharts tag in your search. In the highcharts documentation there will be examples just follow them to the JSfiddle page and read the code and experiment with it. Ity not something to master overnight or explain it in detail in just one comment.  Good Luck